# how to create installer of sh file in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

i m creating one application on ubuntu server in shell script. I write one shell script which runs other perl scripts. i want .exe file of that .sh file

Comment: Are you saying you want to make a .sh file executable?  The .exe file is a convention specific to Windows that is not found on a linux box.

Comment: no i want like when we type yum install apache2 command on terminal and when we press enter then it install all package i want something like that(sory for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just trying to write a shell script.  In that case you just need to create the `.sh` file you want to be executable and then write your shell script as follows (the #!/bin/sh indicates which interpreter to use)

```
#!/bin/sh
... shell commands ...
```

then do a

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

to make it executable.  Then to run it you perform a

```
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: thank you, i knew that, but see let me describe i wrote one shell script and some perl scripts. In shell script i am executing all perl scripts this is all my application do. Now i want to launch this apllication in market but i dont want to give all (sh and perl)scripts i just want to prepare one package and give to user like user when type 'yum install myapplication' on terminal then all my application has to install on his machine automaticaly and run properly can it be possible in ubuntu? Please it is very needful......

Comment: Ah in that case you could use something like pp: http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.009/lib/pp.pm to create an executable from the perl scripts.

Comment: Thank's. i will  check it and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have you application installed via yum, you should package it as an [rpm](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package), put it in a public repository and then make it available to your users.

Comment: Thank's. i am doing that from morning but not worked yet, if it work then i wll let u know

Comment: Then you should post about the specific problems you're facing there.

Comment: rpm -build install not working gives error as 'package not available'

Comment: Well, then post a question, tag it as "rpm" and post your command line, what you're trying to do and what the entire error message was. Someone might respond then.